# how i can fix databinding error while inflate view

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, methods, crash

When I normally I app run after building android studio throws this error.
at com.shayan.test.databinding.ActivityMainBinding.inflate(ActivityMainBinding.java:113)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.shayan.test.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:14)

I think I forget something to do calling method or something
package com.shayan.test

```
package com.shayan.test

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import com.shayan.test.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
        (binding.root)
    }
}
```

Comment: its solved . its for one color of my text view and my API not support that :D

Answer (score 1):

your using viewbinding.. setContentView is missing. and

```
binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this))
```

change to

```
 binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
```

Full code for example

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
```

Comment: i changed it and but still same error

Comment: hi pls refer viewbinding sample code https://github.com/prasanth9689/RecyclerView_ViewBind/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/skyblue/recyclerviewviewbind/MainActivity.kt

Comment: Refer this page https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding

Answer (score 0):

Try this methods :

```
//Try to add in build.gradle (Module:app)
buildFeatures {
viewBinding true
}
```

2:

```
Build -> Clean Project 
Build -> Rebuild Project
```

If this method does not help you then It's not about the Gradle file. It is about the XML file.